# How to select latest record from return set of records ?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL table in SQL server 2008, and I want to get latest record which depends on its date.

E.g. Lets say I have records with some column and a Date column which contain the date of creation of record. 
Lets sat the date column contains following dates. 22-Dec, 23-Dec, 24-Dec, 25,Dec, 26-Dec.

Now , I want to fetch the record which is less than 25 Dec, but I want the latest date record, If I write the query

```
select * from Table where CreateDate < '25-Dec-2012'
```

then It will return 3 records but I want the latest record from them i.e. 24 Dec record

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `TOP 1` to your query, and order it in reverse of its natural order to get your last record first. Assuming that the default order is by `CreateDate` in ascending order, the `ORDER BY CreateDate DESC` should do the trick:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table
WHERE CreateDate < '25-Dec-2012' 
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: Hi, One issue in above query If I use greater than equal to then it wont retrive the latest record.  `SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table
WHERE CreateDate <= '25-Dec-2012'ORDER BY CreateDate DESC`          lets say I have 3 records of 1 jan , 3 jan and 4 jan it gives records of 3ed jan it supposed to give 4th jan record. (As todays date is 4th jan)

Comment: @Nil This usually happens when `CreateDate` is a `DateTime` object: `'25-Dec-2012'` is a midnight; if `CreateDate` has a time portion, it's not going to compare equal. This may be a good subject for a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS, will work fine, checked manually..:)

```
select top 1 * 
from TableName 
where Createdate < '25-Dec-2012' 
order by Createdate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
  top 1 * 
from Table 
  where CreateDate < '25-Dec-2012' 
order by CreateDate desc
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM ProductPrice WHERE  ProductID = 1601 and PriceListCode = 1 
and EffectiveFrom < '25-Dec-2012'
ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC`            is this correct Query ?

Comment: Please check and confirm your result manually, I think there isn't any issue in this query.

Answer (score 0):

use `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE CreateDate < '25-Dec-2012'
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

u can include "Top" as..

```
    select top 1 * from Table where CreateDate < '25-Dec-2012' order by CreateDate desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP said there's only one row per date, so the row with 24-Dec-2012 would be the desired row.

`select * from Table where CreateDate = '24-Dec-2012'`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `order` and `limit`

```
select * from Table where CreateDate < '25-Dec-2012'  order by CreateDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Limit isn't valid in SQL Server